# Moving Files within a hadoop file system(Linux)

Tags: linux

I'm a newbie in linux. I have a directory containing 1000 files. I wish to move 10 files every 10 minutes to another linux dir. I'm confused as to how to do that. Any help will be appreciated. The files in the directory have the same file extension.

EDIT:

I have files in Hadoop FS. I have found many solutions to move in linux. But it turns out many of the commands cannot be used with hadoop fs command arguments. For e.g piping commands doesn't work in most of the cases.

Comment: Wrong site: This isn't a programming question. This should be on SuperUser.

Comment: It sounds like a shell programming question for a class. Right after they teach pipelines and commands like ls, head, mv and sleep.

Comment: I have edited and added more description.

Comment: Without the Hadoop tag the Hadoop experts are not likely to see this.

Answer (score 0):

you can run man on your computer ( wirte "man mv")
http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv

you can use this script

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                   
counter=0                                                                                                                                                     
for f in *                                                                                                                                                    
do                                                                                                                                                            
        if [ "$counter" -le 9 ]                                                                                                                               
        then                                                                                                                                                  
                # move the file                                                                                                                                   
                let counter=counter+1                                                                                                                         
        fi                                                                                                                                                    
done
```

about the 10 min you can add sleep and then run again

Comment: man mv doesn't provide any argument to specify the number of files to move from SRC to DEST

Comment: well you can wirte a script that take a list of all the files in the folder (ls -l) and move the top 10 to other folder and then sleep to X mintus and run again.